# How much jquery in angular app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ember.js

I'm learning javascript and I'm at the point where I can't figure it out on my own, how much do I need to know about jquery to develop app with angular, ember or whatever framework i chose to, **is jquery optional, something good to know but i can do all i wanted just by going with some popular framework**?

Comment: You can never have too much jQuery ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background#answer-15012542

Comment: *"is jQuery optional"* - yes

Comment: [*"I used the jQuery diet plugin and lost 10kg in a week."*](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using jQuery in combination with AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17692340/using-jquery-in-combination-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know anything about jQuery to build an AngularJS application. Angular does come with some jQuery features that they call jqLite. I would focus on getting a basic AngularJs application up and running with the two data-binding functioning then dig into the features in jqLite.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

If you want to know some good practices that still apply with AngularJS I would check out Javascript: The Good Parts by Douglas Crockford.

http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do

If your coming from an object oriented language checking out some transpilers like TypeScript and Babel are a great way to get started. Those transpilers build your javascript files following a lot of the practices outlined in the book I referenced.