# Angular.js Foundation Modal Issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zurb-foundation

So I'm trying to follow this post: [What is the AngularJS way of handling a modal like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966981/what-is-the-angularjs-way-of-handling-a-modal-like-this)

I copied in everything and now I'm getting an error:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'reveal'
```

I'm still trying to learn how all of this works so sorry if this is obvious.

Comment: so http://foundation.zurb.com/ is included proper?

Comment: by the way, you really should show your code in the post and this part is the only relevant part of your error message: `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'reveal'`.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the rest of the error.  I did include foundation.js and foundation.reveal.js

Answer (score 2):

I used to have the same issue, that I was not able to get `Foundation Reveal` to work within my AngularJs App. But I fixed this issue by adding the following code

```
app.run(function($timeout){
    $timeout(function() {
        $(document).foundation();
    }, 500);
});
```

Well, I don't know any explanation for that, but it solved the issue.

### Update:

Now there's an angular port that makes use of foundation javascript plugins. It has support for many foundation javascript plugins including [Modal](http://madmimi.github.io/angular-foundation/#/modal).

[Github repository](https://github.com/pineconellc/angular-foundation) and [demos](http://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/).

Comment: (Foundation or Bootstrap) + AngularJS is a bit of a challenge, since Angular is designed without the jQuery dom manipulation paradigm. AngularUI is essentially bootstrap written in the Angular paradigm. There's talk of the AngularUI team providing Foundation support at some point in the future, but until then, getting the two frameworks to cooperate will always be an uphill battle.